# Calculating determinant of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-exponential

> Calculate det $(e^A)$ when A= $
>                                 \begin{pmatrix}
>                                 1 & 0 & 3\\
>                                 -1 & 2 & 0 \\
>                                 0 & 1 & -1 \\
>                                 \end {pmatrix}
>                                 $ without calculating det $e^A$.

The matrix A is diagonalizable matrix than i can use the formula det $(e^A)$=$e^{tr(A)}$, but the problem comes when i try to calculate eigenvalues. The characteristic polynomial is: $-λ^3 + 2 λ^2 + λ - 5$ which impossible to solve without wolfarm alpha.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the characteristic polynomial since the formula $\det(e^A)=e^{tr(A)}$ always holds. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential

Comment: You should just compute $\operatorname{tr}(A)$. Then it is very easy.

Comment: so how did wolfarm get to the next result? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+e%5E%7B%7B1,0,3%7D,%7B-1,2,0%7D,%7B0,1,-1%7D%7D

Comment: Wolfram is computing $e^ A$ as [follows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B%7B1,0,3%7D,%7B-1,2,0%7D,%7B0,1,-1%7D%7D). This seems wrong.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mean it's not wrong. It's just something completely different.

Comment: @MaikPickl  So in summary the answer to my question is $e+e^2+e^{-1}$ and what wolfarm alpha calculates is something different from the question?

Comment: Almost: $e^{tr(A)}=e^{1+2-1}\neq e+e^2+e^{-1}$. And yes: wolfram is calculating something different.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Wolfram interprets [`E^{{1,0,3},{-1,2,0},{0,1,-1}}`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=E%5E%7B%7B1,0,3%7D,%7B-1,2,0%7D,%7B0,1,-1%7D%7D) as element-wise exponentiation. To get the matrix exponential use [`MatrixExp[{{1,0,3},{-1,2,0},{0,1,-1}}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp%5B%7B%7B1,0,3%7D,%7B-1,2,0%7D,%7B0,1,-1%7D%7D%5D).

Comment: @lastresort Thank you! However, it was not me using this command - see comment of the OP at the beginning. I just wanted to show the OP that this command does the "wrong" thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Corollary), one can get the identity:
$$ \det(e^{tA}) = e^{\text{tr}(tA)} $$
which is formula you want when $t=1$. This case *always* holds for any fixed $A$, so you don't need to worry about the characteristic polynomial. This is because you only need $e^A$ to be invertible, which it always is.

Maybe it's also worth noting that, in the *real* case, [you can't generally write any matrix $A$ as $A=e^X$ for some $X$, unless $ \det(A)> 0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369534/problem-with-jacobis-formula-for-determinants).

Thus,  we get: $$ \det(e^A) = e^{\text{tr}(A)} = e^{1+2-1} = e^2$$